# Programmatically close the window created by `View(x)`

Tags: r

I'm viewing a dataframe in R using `View`:

```
my_df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
View(my_df)
```

**I'd like to now close the resulting window programmatically (rather than clicking the X button).**

How may I do this? `graphics.off` doesn't work as it isn't a graphics device. Looking at the `View` code, internal function `dataviewer` is used to display the window but I'm not sure what it uses in the background (tcltk?) so am not sure how to close the window.

---

Re some comments as to why I want this.

I'm basically doing a user-checking step in a script whereby the user is asked if a snippet of a dataframe and a corresponding image go together. It goes something like this:

```
for (i in 1:heaps) {

    1. View(a snippet of a big dataframe)
    2. show an image

    3. readline('Is this OK? [Y/N]: ') (store the i for which it's not OK)

    4. close the image window (graphics.off()), close the View(..) window.
}
```

I basically wanted to reduce the user interaction down staring at the image & dataframe snippet and typing Y or N, so they don't have to manually close th dataframe window for each `i` in the loop.

(I'm part-way through this validation myself and am dealing with 200 `View(snippet)` windows that I haven't bothered to close D:. Also, have noticed that the opening of the windows steals keyboard focus away from the prompt so me typing Y/N is not as fast as I'd like. But I only have to do this once, so it'll do for now. I am curious as to the answer to the question though, for next time).

Comment: It seems to me that `View` is an interactive tool by excellence, so it seems a little contradictory that you'd like to close it *programmatically*. Out of curiosity, could you elaborate how you want to use `View` in a programmatic context? Versus for example writing `my_df` to a csv for potential review. I still hope  someone will come with a nice answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a line of code to run (one you will have to run anyway manually) to close the window. So if you were to source the code, it would instantly open and close the window?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation as to my motivation in the question. I am basically asking the user to compare some rows of the dataframe with an image and type Y/N whether they match or not (user validation). Just wanting to make this as easy as possible as it's me doing the validation!

Comment: Your OS might be relevant if it involves finding and killing xterm processes.

Comment: Two notes: I ran `View` from the OSX r.app gui, and then switched to X11 and hit <CMD>-Q .  The R-gui spit out "Error: ignoring SIGPIPE signal" , and recommended that I quit and restart R.  Now, it's not **too** hard to write a system call from R that will kill a different process, if that's really what you want to do.  I just wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you use `gWidgets` to show the tables you can programmatically close them.

Comment: consider `plotrix::addtable2plot`.

Comment: There are two ways of answering this question. One is to answer it as it is and find a way to close a View() window. The other is to emulate View() in something we *can* close. @flodel and @jverzani have made a couple of suggestions in this regard. I suggest the `rdataviewer` package, which can open graphics windows.

Comment: Did my solution of using wmctrl work for you?

Comment: It does, though it is a shame that the only way to close a `View()` window is (seemingly) to install `wmctrl` and spawn it external to R, relying on the window titles to be unique (and if you make to `View(x)` calls they won't be). In future I'll follow @sebastian-c's suggestion and check out `rdataviewer`

Comment: Agreed. wmctrl can do more than close based on window titles. It can make use of window IDs too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you're after is to make use of the `system` function. You could, for example, determine the Window ID/Name and then issue a close command like so:

```
system('(sleep 10; wmctrl -c "Data: my_df") &')
```

The above command will wait 10 seconds, and then issue a command to the window manager to close any window with the name **"Data: my_df"**. These 2 commands are wrapped in parens. This is known as a **Compound Command** in bash. The entire **Compound Command** is backgrounded, '&'.

I tested the following and it worked:

```
# sample1.R
my_df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
system('(sleep 10; wmctrl -c "Data: my_df") &')
View(my_df)
```

Another way to accomplish this is like so:

```
# sample2.R
my_df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
View(my_df)
system('read -p "Press [Enter] key to start backup..."')
my_df2 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
View(my_df2)
system('read -p "Press [Enter] key to start backup..."')
```

I'm running these like this:

```
R CMD BATCH sample2.R
```

**NOTE:** The prompt from the `read -p` command isn't showing up in my terminal but you could just print a duplicate prompt message in R.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to close all open "View" windows, building on the answer of slm :

```
CloseViews <- function(){
    cmd <- paste0('wmctrl -c "Data:" -v')
    ok <- TRUE
    while(ok){
        out <- suppressWarnings(system(cmd,intern=TRUE,ignore.stderr=TRUE))
        Sys.sleep(0.2)
        ok <- is.null(attr(out,"status"))
        print(ok)
    }
}
```

Then `CloseViews()` does the trick, which I found particularly helpful when working interactively.