# alternative to gwidgets or View for displaying and updating a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, gwidgets

I'm trying to display a large data.table but I'm getting caught between the sluggishness of a `gtable` from `gWidgets` with `RGtk2` and the inflexibility of `View` from base.  As an example I could have

```
ex<-data.table(AA=runif(50000,-10,10),
               BB=runif(50000,-10,10),
               CC=runif(50000,-10,10),
               DD=runif(50000,-10,10),
               EE=runif(50000,-10,10),
               FF=runif(50000,-10,10),
               GG=runif(50000,-10,10),
               HH=runif(50000,-10,10),
               II=runif(50000,-10,10),
               JJ=runif(50000,-10,10),
               KK=runif(50000,-10,10),
               LL=runif(50000,-10,10),
               MM=runif(50000,-10,10))
```

when I do `View(ex)` it takes a second to populate.  If I do

```
gwin<-gwindow(title="example")
gtab<-gtable(ex,container=gwin)
```

it will take 59 seconds.

My problem with a `View` window is that if my script needs to update it, the user has to manually close the window and a new one has to be reopened.  My problem with the `gWidgets gtable` is that in my actual script the output is about a million rows (give or take) which often causes R to crash before the results are populated and always takes longer than is acceptable.

I don't need, or want, the user to be able to edit the underlying table through the display.  Really, what `View` displays is all I need except if the underlying table changes I want to be able to have the window change as opposed to being forced to close the old and open a new.

I saw this question [Programmatically close the window created by `View(x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349868/programmatically-close-the-window-created-by-viewx) which implies there's no way to update `View` windows.

I saw in that same question someone made reference to the plotrix package but I don't want any plots, I just want the table which it doesn't seem to do.

Is there another package that will give me the speed of a `View` with the ability to programmatically change the window after it is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try gdfedit. It is a simple front end to dfedit on RGtk2Extras. Otherwise, there is a model in Rgtk2 that makes this easy enough. Here is a fairly minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e5), y = rnorm(1e5))

library(RGtk2)
model <- rGtkDataFrame(df)
view <- gtkTreeView(model)
mapply(view$insertColumnWithAttributes,  -1, colnames(model), 
       list(gtkCellRendererText()), 
       text = seq_len(ncol(model)) - 1)

sw <- gtkScrolledWindow()
sw$add(view)

win <- gtkWindow(show=FALSE)
win$add(sw)
win$show()
```

This should display this size data set very quickly. I would guess 1e6 is no problem too. I'll let you try. This example comes from the ProgGUIinR package where the code from the book *Programming GUIs in R* is given. Not plugging the book, but giving you a place to look for some other things that can be done.

This does not synchronize the GUI to the data frame, though the model itself (`model`) can be accessed through `[<-` and those changes are reflected.

Comment: could you elaborate on the usage of the model in Rgtk2 that you are alluding to please